# How to draw a circle inside Border Container using graphics object?

Tags: apache-flex, graphics, flex4, draw, border-container

My basic requirement is to draw a circle inside a `BorderContainer` with the layout set to BasicLayout

I run this method in the `CREATION_COMPLETE` event of the BorderContainer object.

```
   this.graphics.beginFill(0xff0000);
   this.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0x00ff00);
   this.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 50);
   this.graphics.endFill();
```

Sorry to be blunt, but why don't I see anything? I know I must be missing something VERY basic here. Can I just draw like this OR should I draw in some other event?

P.S: I know that I can create a Ellipse object and easily add it to the border container but I would like to know how I can do this using the graphics object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Back in the olden days you would override updateDisplayList and do this sort of drawing there.  I'm guessing things are getting refreshed at some point AFTER creation complete.  Since you are drawing rather than adding an object to the stage, your circle isn't really part of any kind of lifecycle and will get wiped clean whenever the display list is dirtied/redrawn.  Hope that helps.

Comment: The issue I had is, I could create a new Ellipse object and then add it to BordnerContainer. It works, but also it makes the application painfully slow.

Comment: In that case I would move your drawing code to an overridden updateDisplayList function for your BorderContainer.

Answer (score 2):

I see two possible problems.

1. you forget to add BorderContainer
   object to the stage
2. *this* is no reference of your
   BorderContainer object. Try to trace
   *this* in your event listner, or
   change it to target or currenTarget

Answer (score 0):

```
var _shape:Shape=new Shape();
addchild(_shape);

_shape.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0x000000, 1);
_shape.graphics.drawRect(10,5,100,100);
```

Using the above code will show a rectangle on your screen.